# Bootstrap-table text truncate

Tags: html, json, bootstrap-table

I’m currently using Bootstrap-table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) with the bootstrap-editable extension (https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/editable) to create a table with editable fields. I have noticed that when a string contains qoutes for example: this is a "test" the string is being truncated on the first ". I have noticed that the text is correctly saved in the database, the JSON contains the full text (" not escaped).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the *text-overflow* property to *clip* or *initial* for the cell where your text is being truncated.
This will help https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: This seems applicable if the text is too long for the given space.  This however does not seem to be the case in my particular case (there are much longer texts that are correctly shown). Or am I missing something?

Comment: JSON splits the segment by finding the next " symbol (I'm not 100% sure). Check your response in the browser console and compare with your output. I think whenever it finds a " symbol, it takes it as the end of that value. Use single quote instead of double quote.

Comment: Based on preliminary tests seems escaping the " character seems the solution to my problem.  Thanks.